# How can I get the sum of a user input array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, input, user-input

I'm trying to figure out how to get this done:

```js
let birdsCalories = 250;
let deerCalories = 1000;
let fishCalories = 900;

function animalCalorieCalculator() {
    let repeat, userAnimalCalories = [];

    while(repeat !== "no") {
      userAnimalCalories.push(prompt("Which animals do you have?"));

      repeat = prompt("Would you like to add more animals? Yes/No");
      document.getElementById("totalCalories").innerHTML = userAnimalCalories;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="calc">
         <button onclick="animalCalorieCalculator()" class="dropbtn">Start</button>
         <p id="totalCalories"></p>
      </div>
```

What I need this to do is :
1. The user can only choose birds, deer or fish
2. In the end, depending on what they have filled this array with, i need a sum of their calories

I have an idea of how it works, but I just can't get it actually to work. I added this to my code, but it ruined everything

```
userAnimalCalories = userAnimalCalories.toLowerCase();
if (userAnimalCalories === 'birds' || userAnimalCalories === 'deer' || userAnimalCalories === 'fish') {
    return userAnimalCalories;
} else {
    return 'You can only add birds, deer or fish';
}
```

Any ideas of how to solve this?

Comment: I think instead of using a user prompt, you should use a dropdown so the user is forced to choose only bird, fish, or deer. The first rule of UX is limit your user's choices as much as possible without letting them realize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this:

```js
function animalCalorieCalculator() {
  const animals = []; // only need to store which animals were added
  let calories = 0;
  while (true) {
    const animal = prompt("Which animal do you want to add?");

    // validate the animal before adding it to the array
    switch (animal) {
      case "deer":
        calories += 1000;
        animals.push(animal);
        break;
      case "fish":
        calories += 250;
        animals.push(animal);
        break;
      case "bird":
        calories += 900;
        animals.push(animal);
        break;
      default: // not deer, fish, or bird
        alert("Invalid animal.");
        break;
    }

    document.getElementById("totalCalories").innerHTML = calories.toString();

    // changed this to a confirmation
    if (!confirm("Would you like to add more animals?")) break;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="calc">
  <button onclick="animalCalorieCalculator()" class="dropbtn">Start</button>
  <p id="totalCalories"></p>
</div>
```

If you only want to show the user how many calories they added, then you don't even need the `animals` array and you can just delete it and all references to it.

Answer (score 1):

first of all you need make array that has all the elements so you can loop thru them.

also entering user option as prompt option is not the best thing to do as you have to to enter the same exact word from very specific options

also you if you use string like "no" your answer has to be no (match upper cases)

I have logged the answer to the console and you can move them to the document incase you you want to continue practicing

```
const bird = 250;
const deer = 1000;
const fish = 900;
let totalCalories = 0;


function animalCalorieCalculator() {


  const animalsArray = [bird, deer, fish]
  const animalsNamesArray = ['bird', 'deer', 'fish']

  const answer = prompt("Which animals do you have?", "");
  let confirm = prompt("Would you like to add more animals? yes/no", "");

  for (let i = 0; i < animalsArray.length; i++) {

    if (answer === animalsNamesArray[i]) {

      totalCalories = totalCalories + animalsArray[i]
      console.log('totalCalories = ' + totalCalories)

    }

  }

  if (confirm === 'yes') {
    animalCalorieCalculator()
  }

}
```